# How to generically log the affected string in a FormatException?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, exception

```
DateTime MyDateTime;
try{
    MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(datestring, MyCultureInfo).Date;
    //many other lines
}catch(Exception e){
    Log(e);
}
```

I have a parsing-function where, among other, a `string` is converted to a `DateTime` object. Most of the time this works, but sometimes the input string can be in a different DateFormat, or has some additional strings in it, and then conversion fails.
**To handle these cases I need to know which strings caused problems.** The exception message won't tell me:

> System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.

Even as converted into `FormatException` the exception object does not provide the problematic input string:

```
try{
    MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(datestring, MyCultureInfo).Date;
    //many other lines
}catch(FormatException e){
    Log(e);
}
```

What do I need to do to get a Log like this?

> System.FormatException: The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.
>   Input: '2019.02.20'

Sure I could embrace every line in the code with a single try-catch-block

```
DateTime MyDateTime;
try{
    MyDateTime = DateTime.Parse(datestring, MyCultureInfo).Date;
}catch(Exception e){
    Log(e);
    Log($"Input: '{datestring}'");
}
try{
  //many other lines
}catch(Exception e){
    Log(e);
}
```

But that sucks.

Answer (score 2):

> But that sucks.

Yes it does. When you start properly handling and logging errors, your code size goes up.

Most logging frameworks have a `Log` method which takes an exception and an additional message. In that case, you can probably write something like:

```
Log(e, $"Unable to parse DateTime {datestring}");
```

You could of course create a wrapper method around `DateTime.Parse`, which throws its own exception. Something like:

```
private static DateTime ParseDate(string input)
{
    try
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(input, MyCultureInfo).Date;
    }
    catch (FormatException e)
    {
        throw new FormatException($"Unable to parse DateTime '{input}': {e.Message}", e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Mhhh I think I like the idea of throwing my own exception. The parsing function is in fact implemented in a library which is used by many programs, so it wouldn't be that much overhead. Thanks for the tip, hadn't thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you will have to cater for every place where it would fail to enable you to include the string. Although I would avoid coding by exception and code to assume it will fail. E.g.

```
    var dateTimeString = "2015494";
    if(!DateTime.TryParse(dateTimeString, out DateTime result))
    {
        Log();
    }
```